# Sample/Species Transformation code assistance

Tags: r, optimization, matrix, transformation

I'm trying to simplify a task in **R**. I have a community matrix as such:

```
row.name   species1  species2 species3 species4 .... species50
sample 1      1         6        156      4              1
sample 2      0        20        34       5              1
sample 3      3         7        23       0              7
....
sample 10     3        15        9        7              6
```

These are raw count figures

I'm trying to code (but getting nowhere) a means by which I can cap any species which occurs >10% in a sample/row, to 9%. I.e in this (made up) example it would seem sample1/species3 may need capping.

I would like the the data kept as/reverted back to a raw count. Is this even possible within **R**?

I'm aware of the ecology transformations in `vegan` or equivalent to normalise/standardise data, but they are not what I am after here.

I hope that makes sense. If not I can try explain again. Any help greatly appreciated, still fairly new with **R**.

Comment: Do you mean any value in the matrix > 10 should be replaced with 9?  On re-read, probably not.  But 10% of what? Of row sums? Column sums?

Comment: Sorry, 10% of row sum

Comment: this might get tricky if there are two species whose counts are greater than 10% - once you change one species' count you may find that another species count jumps up to comprising >=10% of the rowsum because the rowsum is dynamic, then you're moving into optimisation territory I think. do the replaced counts have to equal 9% exactly?

Comment: Yes, this was my thought. I was wondering whether R could respond/balance this dynamically. They don't have to equal 9% exactly, but <10% .. typically in my datasets majority of species comprise 1-7% of each sample. One or two will be greater than 10% (v. v. rarely 3).

Comment: I'll add optimisation to the tags!

Answer (score 1):

I would use `sweep()`, but specify `pmin` as the function so that it
takes the smaller of 10% and the actual value:

```
M <- read.table(header=TRUE, row.names = 'row.name', 
text='row.name   species1  species2 species3 species4  species50
sample_1      1         6        156      4              1
sample_2      0        20        34       5              1
sample_3      3         7        23       0              7
sample_10     3        15        9        7              6') 

M <- as.matrix(M)

sweep(M, 1, rowSums(M) %/% 10, pmin)
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll check this out, which package is sweep in? :)

Comment: @Geoff The return of the possibly adjusted raw values was a real challenge to me.  Your approach is very clever!

Comment: sweep(Data, 1, rowSums(Data) %/% 10, pmin)
Error in FUN(x, aperm(array(STATS, dims[perm]), order(perm)), ...) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'                                                    I get this error? (sorry I cant work out how to make that look like r script)

Comment: You can't use a data.frame, you have to convert to a matrix first.

Comment: oh ok (ignore answer below!!)

Comment: @Neal, +1 for elegant approach. Following replacement of values >10% of ```rowSums()```, the other non-altered values in the row are re-scaled, with some values comprising more than 10% in the new matrix. In addition, the replaced values aren't necessarily less than 10% of the new rowsum. E.g.: New matrix: `N <- sweep(M, 1, rowSums(M) %/% 10, pmin)` Compare relative percentages between old and new matrices:
`M/rowSums(M)*100; N/rowSums(N)*100`

Comment: Thanks for input, this is really useful .. your solution stops just short of what I was looking for although it does go half way. I'm still checking through all the data (over 500 species), but it has certainly dampened some of the worse excess, whilst yes, another species becomes just over 10%.

Comment: You should divide by the original row totals, not the new one. Otherwise you are changing both the numerator and denominator and it's nonlinear. Imagine as above, you have 5 cols, threshold at 10%. (10,10,10,10,10) would change to (5,5,5,5,5). If you divide by 50, everything is 10%; if you divide by 25, it's 20%. How are you dealing with that in your data?